# How can I use the vtkStreamTracer class to generate a streamline with my unstructured grid data(vtu)

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm using the `VTK` and `C++` to visualize data coming from xflow in vtu. When I use the Paraview, it can generate the right streamline, but when I use the `VTK` to visualize my data, it only displays the outline and the airplane model. There is no streamline being generated.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkNamedColors> namedColors = vtkSmartPointer<vtkNamedColors>::New();

//The AirplaneModel file
std::string meshfilename = "K:/Project/VTKproject/Airplane_Process/data/Mesh.vtp";
vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataReader> meshreader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataReader>::New();
meshreader->SetFileName(meshfilename.c_str());
meshreader->Update();

//The data file
std::string datafilename ="K:/Project/VTKproject/Airplane_Process/data/data.vtu";
vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader> datareader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader>::New();
datareader->SetFileName(datafilename.c_str());
datareader->Update();

//The seed points
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPointSource> seeds = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPointSource>::New();
seeds->SetCenter(0,0,0);
seeds->SetRadius(0.05);
seeds->SetNumberOfPoints(100);


//streamline generate

vtkSmartPointer<vtkStreamTracer> streamline = vtkSmartPointer<vtkStreamTracer>::New();
datareader->Update();
streamline->SetInputConnection(datareader->GetOutputPort());
streamline->SetSourceConnection(seeds->GetOutputPort());
//streamline->SetIntegrationStepUnit(vtkStreamTracer::CELL_LENGTH_UNIT);
streamline->SetMaximumPropagation(500);
streamline->SetMaximumIntegrationStep(0.1);
streamline->SetMinimumIntegrationStep(0.01);
streamline->SetInitialIntegrationStep(0.05);
//streamline->SetIntegrationStepUnit(vtkStreamTracer::CELL_LENGTH_UNIT);
streamline->SetIntegrationDirectionToBoth();
streamline->SetIntegratorTypeToRungeKutta45();
streamline->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> streamLineMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
streamLineMapper->SetInputConnection(streamline->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> streamLineActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
streamLineActor->SetMapper(streamLineMapper);

//outlinefilter
vtkSmartPointer<vtkOutlineFilter> outline =vtkSmartPointer<vtkOutlineFilter>::New();
outline->SetInputConnection(datareader->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> outlineMapper =vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
outlineMapper->SetInputConnection(outline->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> outlineActor =vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
outlineActor->SetMapper(outlineMapper);
outlineActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(0,0,0);

//
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> meshmapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
meshmapper->SetInputConnection(meshreader->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> meshactor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
meshactor->SetMapper(meshmapper);

//rendering
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderer->AddActor(meshactor);
renderer->AddActor(outlineActor);
renderer->AddActor(streamLineActor);
//renderer->AddActor(actor);
renderer->SetBackground(namedColors->GetColor3d("Cadet").GetData());
//window
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

//interaction
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera> style =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera>::New();
renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle(style);
renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
renderWindow->SetSize(300, 300);
renderWindow->Render();
renderWindowInteractor->Start();
```

This is my desired output generated in paraview
[image: This is my desired output generated in paraview]

This is the result of my code:

[image: This is the result of my code:]

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been searching more or less the same thing. I tried your code on my data. And I also didnt see the result. On the other hand I did a debug statement :

```
streamline->Print(std::cout);

streamline->GetOutput()->Print(std::cout);
```

and my result is :

```
vtkPStreamTracer (0x555c851095d0)



Debug: Off

  Modified Time: 1444545

  Reference Count: 2

  Registered Events: (none)

  Executive: 0x555c854fb270

  ErrorCode: Success

  Information: 0x555c8556c100

  AbortExecute: Off

  Progress: 1

  Progress Text: (None)

  Start position: 0 0 0

  Terminal speed: 1e-12

  Maximum propagation: 500 unit: length.

  Integration step unit: cell length.

  Initial integration step: 0.05

  Minimum integration step: 0.01

  Maximum integration step: 0.1

  Integration direction: both directions.

  Integrator: 0x555c85572320

  Maximum error: 1e-06

  Maximum number of steps: 2000

  Vorticity computation:  On

  Rotation scale: 1

  Controller: 0
```

So I think the problem might be more about something else ?

Have you already solved it ?

Sorry I'm new here also, couldnt find the "comment" button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but the problem have not be solved.Have you ever visualize the data in vtu successfully?If you have,is there any difference with your code?

Comment: No, I am at the same point with you. the bigger problem for me is, its not a real "vtu" file but rather an unstructered grid(basicly a point cloud with some data)  still searching for solutions.

Comment: Hello,The problem have been solved.Firstly,you should make sure that your unstructured grid have a set of vector data.Then , you should let the streamtracer know which data array will be used to generate the streamline by using the streamtracer->SetInputArrayToProcess or the vtkAssignAttribute class.

Comment: @Stargazer0205: Can you share the code line where you set the InputArray? I am struggling with the same problem and *SetInputArrayToProcess* didn't solve my problem yet.

Comment: just like this: streamtracer->SetInputArrayToProcess(0, 0, 0, vtkDataObject::FIELD_ASSOCIATION_CELLS, "Velocity") .You should change your code according to your data.@SteScheller